# Суммирование чисел из строки с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: java

Код не возвращает суммированные числа. В коде ход рассуждений.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей";
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    public static int calculateSalarySum(String text) {
        // будем искать числа, начиная с границы слова
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+");
        // будем искать числа в строке text
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        // сумма чисел пока равна 0
        Integer sum = 0;
        //пока в тексте находятся числа
        while (m.find()) {
            // они суммируются в виде int
            sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        }
        //возвращаем
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: так а где вызов метода `calculateSalarySum`? ))

Comment: Да, увидел. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если написать  `sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(0));` вместо  `sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));`, то всё работает

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей";
    System.out.println(calculateSalarySum(text));
}

public static int calculateSalarySum(String text) {        
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+");        
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    Integer sum = 0;
    
    while (m.find()) {    
        sum += Integer.parseInt(m.group(0));
    }
    
    return sum;
}
```

---

Проверял тут: https://ideone.com/8TQoNs

Проверить в IDE не могу)

Comment: Заменил 0 на 1, и еще заметил огромный промах в своем коде, не обращался к calculateSalarySum. Работает только на Ideone. Большое спасибо, я увидел, где слажал.

Answer (score 0):

с регуляркой перемудрили) вот ваша рабочая.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
```